# Removing 3 specific characters, if present from the start of a string VB.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, replace, trim

I have a situation where I need remove a prefix from a string, if it exists.

```
Dim str As String = "samVariable"
```

Needs to be converted to `Variable`

Easy, with `TrimStart`

```
str = str.trimstart("s"c, "a"c, "m"c)
```

Except...

The string might *not* always start with "sam"

Example:

```
Dim str As String = "saleDetails"
```

This will now become `aleDetails`

Which is wrong, so how about `Replace`

```
str = str.Replace('sam','')
```

Brilliant! Now:

Example 1:

```
Dim str As String = "samVariable"
str = str.Replace('sam','')
str = "Variable"
```

Example 2:

```
Dim str As String = "saleDetails"
str = str.Replace('sam','')
str = "saleDetails" (unaffected)
```

BUT....

What if:

```
Dim str As String = "Resample"
str = str.Replace('sam','')
str = "Reple"
```

This is *wrong* again!

So, my question is:

How do I remove "sam" from the beginning of a string only?

I had expected `TrimStart("sam")` to work, but it doesn't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if str.StartsWith("sam")
    str = str.Substring(3)
end if
```

Not a one-liner, but easy to follow.

Comment: Upvoted your second option, because I like the simple one line nature, but I am going to accept this answer (in 8 minutes when SO let's me!) as I think it is easier to follow.

Comment: I prefer this one to the regular expression as well - regexes can be awesome, but I almost always prefer readability.

Comment: The difference in this case is the regex engine does a strncmp(p, "sam", 3), then a strcpy(p[3], dest) all within the engine. All the middle men are cut out, making it at least twice as fast as your method.

Comment: @sln I don't know about the internal workings of either method, but in my basic tests for this specific case, the regular expression takes consistently about 4-5 times as long to run as the startswith/substring one. Still negligible in the real world (130/700ms for 1 million iterations), but that's a big difference.

Comment: @Joe Enos - That seems kind of odd. The two lines above don't compile to the C equivalent. A regex engine does, but I guess it depends upon if the regex is pre-compiled and constant. Finding "^sam" and replacing with "" is optimized to the equivalent C code. So, it could be the overhead of enterring the engine that you are recording, because there is just overwrite using strcpy(). How did you use a regex and how do you benchmark it?

Comment: @sln Just ran again where I instantiated the regex only one time in advance and used that - improved quite a bit, but StartsWith/Substring is still about twice as fast. All I did for the test is start a stopwatch, loop 1 million times with `string s = "SamVariable"; s = Regex.Replace(s, "^sam", "");` and record the stopwatch time - then repeated again with a single instance of regex, and again with the StartsWith/Substring. Single instance of Regex about 400ms, Static call 700ms, Substring 130ms. Loop the whole thing in a `while (true)` and I'm getting consistent results.

Comment: @Joe Enos - Sounds about right, the overhead of enterring the engine. It should scale if s = "SamSamSamSamVar" and while s.StartsWith() s = Substring() end while. And probably cheating if s = Regex.Replace(s, "^(?:sam)+", "") so that can't count.

Answer (score 4):

```
str = New Regex("^sam").Replace(str, String.Empty)
```

The regular expression looks for `sam` at the start of the string and replaces it with empty, effectively removing the `sam` from the beginning.

**EDIT** Per Konrad's comment, the shared method call would be better:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, "^sam", String.Empty)
```

Comment: No need to construct a `Regex` instance if you don’t save it – use the shared method instead. Oh, and `String.Empty` is an abomination. It’s six times longer than `""` and none the clearer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks, you're right, the static one would be better, answer updated. As far as the `""` vs. `String.Empty` goes, there's plenty of debate on that one, so it's up to what you consider readable. I personally prefer `String.Empty` (or `string.Empty` in C#).

Comment: Just came across this comment, 4 years later, and apparently I've evolved a bit. I prefer `""` now. Maybe it's because I'm getting older and wiser, or maybe arthritis is starting to kick in and I want to type less...who knows...

Comment: I prefer vbNullString. Easier on memory and speed. But still only a preference.